# Datatables Server Side - Using HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I use to datatables with server side option it is working but I pull some record from sql table and then I want to some column add html tags  but it doesn't work I couldn't find a simple document. Can you help with this

Best Regards.

Js code is below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "server_side/server_processing.php",
        }
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Server-side code is below

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'name',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'phone',   'dt' => 2 ),

);
```

i want it to be **phone** column in ajax file for example is below

```
<a href="tel:phone">phone</a>
```

thank you for your answer in advance

Comment: please refer : https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/server-side-processing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is my way to fix your problem, let me know if it works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "server_side/server_processing.php"
        },
        columnDefs: [{
            targets: 2,
            render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                if (type === 'display') {
                    data = '<a href="tel:' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                }

                return data;
            }
        }]
    });
});
```